# How do I know if two dates are in the same week in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I know if two dates are in the same week in PHP?

Example week 52 of 2020 that starts on the 21st and ends on the 26th, I have two dates as an example the 22nd and the 27th and I would like to check if these two dates are in the same week, return true or false

Comment: Define the same week? 1) within 7 days of each other? 2) Within the same week number? 3) something else completely?

Comment: What day does the week start on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your are referring to ISO-8601 week number of year, you may use the W parameter for date, which will give ISO-8601 week number of year

```
<?php

echo date('W' ,strtotime('2020-12-23'));
// the above gives 52

echo "<br>";

echo date('W' , strtotime('2020-12-28'));
// the above gives 53

?>
```

Comment: You can also go OOP using PHP's DateTime::format() method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Just giving an example to what @uotonyh said: `if (DateTime('2020-12-23')->format('W') == DateTime('2020-12-28')->format('W')) { ... }`
The only problem might occur when using DateTime with variables: bad variable => errors. `date($bad_variable)` seems to bypass errors by just resulting `false` on comparison.